# JS объекты. Вложенные объекты. Изменение свойства

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
let animal1 = {
  eats: true,
}

let animal2 = {
  eats: true,
  test: '3',
  obj: animal1,
}

animal1 = {
  eats: false,
}

console.log(animal2.obj) // true
```

Пожалуйста объясните как это работает. Понимаю, что если делать так
 `animal1.eats = false` то всё работает. Но очень хочу понять почему не работает по другому.

Comment: Эм. Потому что в одном случае Вы модифицируете объект, а в другом просто создаёте новый.

Comment: *Но очень хочу понять почему не работает по другому.* - что значит по другому?

Comment: в объекте 2 свойство `obj` хранит ссылку на первое объявление, соответственно меняя свойства, ссылка не меняется. Но когда вы переопределили `animal1`,ссылка на него поменялась. Но в объекте `animal2` все та же старая ссылка осталась на первоначальный объект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let animal1 = {
  name: "заяц",   
}

let animal2 = {
  name: 'волк',
  food: animal1, // заяц
}

// сейчас у нас два указателя на объект "заяц";
console.log(animal1.name) //заяц
console.log(animal2.food.name) //заяц

//если вы будете изменять любые свойства первого объекта не меняя
// сам объект то свойства объекта вложенного во второй объект
// так же будут меняться

animal1.name = "гусь";

// мы не меняли объект а только изменили его свойства
console.log(animal1.name) //гусь
console.log(animal2.food.name) //гусь

animal1 = {
  name: "черепаха"
}

//а здесь мы переопределили переменную animal1 теперь это другой объект;
console.log(animal1.name) //черепаха
console.log(animal2.food.name) //гусь
//при этом ссылка внутри второго объекта по прежнему указывает
// на объект который мы присвоили ей изначально
```